# Converting PCM-ALAW data to an audio file using ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encode

In my project, I processed the received RTP packets with the payload, and extracted all the payload to a separate buffer. This payload is - PCM ALAW (Type 8). How do I implement a class that will take as arguments - the file name and a buffer with raw data to create an audio file. Exactly what steps do I have to go through in order to encode raw data into an audio file? As an example, I used [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/2635152445/) example.

Comment: Well you did say "using ffmpeg". Do you know how to do it using ffmpeg? Without all the Qt stuff.

Comment: I mean about using the ffmpeg library

Comment: Do you know how to do it using ffmpeg? Without all the Qt stuff.

Comment: No. I tried using the example that I specified in the question, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Why didn't it help you?

Comment: In the example, for example, it is specified that for WAV audio format, we will use the AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE codec with certain parameters of the audio context. But in my case, I get already processed audio data in PCM-ALAW format. When selecting this codec (AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_ALAW), I also specify the audio context settings, namely: bit_rate=64000, sample_rate=8000, sample_fmt=AV_SAMPLE_FMT_U8P, and so on. But here I have a problem. The library says that it can't support the AV_SAMPLE_FT_U8P sample format. But the RTP documentation with a type 8 payload says that the sample size is 8 bits.

Comment: I also have another problem. The example shows how we process raw data one-time and save it to an audio file instantly. But my conditions are very different. When getting an Rtp packet with a payload, I have to extract this payload and write it to an audio file. There is no problem with extraction, but writing this small piece of data to an audio file is already a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds way too complex. "PCM ALAW" is a bit misleading, but it's pretty clear that G.711 aLaw encoding is meant. That's a trivial "compression" which maps each 16 bits PCM sample to an 8 bits value. So a trivial lookup fixes that.

There's even a Free [implementation](http://www.speech.kth.se/cost250/refsys/v1.0/src/g711.c) of the aLaw encoding available. Just convert each sample to 16 bits PCM, stuff a standard Microsoft WAVE header in front of it, and call the result `.WAV`.

You'll need to fill in a few WAV headers based on the RTP type 8. Chiefly, that's "Mono, 8000 Hz, 16 bits per sample". One small problem with the header is that you can only write the full header once you know how many samples you have. You could update the header whenever you receive a RTP packet, but that's a bit I/O intensive. It might be nicer to do that once per 10 packets or so.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I didn't know that PCM-ALAW is introduced in S16.
I originally thought about encoding a-law in liner, but FFMPEG has a great tool for this - [swr_convert](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lswr.html#gaa5bb6cab830146efa8c760fa66ee582a). But still I tried your suggestion and it didn't help :(

Comment: @bbdd: I've got code which does exactly (RTP to WAV) that in the project I'm working on right now. Did you even try the `alaw2linear` function from the link I sent you? `swr_convert` is WAY harder. That is not a great tool in comparison. `alaw2linear` takes one aLaw sample from your RTP stream and returns one sample for your WAV file. One in, one out, it doesn't get simpler than that.

Comment: I tried using alaw2liner, but unfortunately I completely lost the sound. Before that, there was a very strong noise + voice.

Comment: If you want, we can go to the chat for convenience.